# Search pattern in directory and extract string from files using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

I have almost 400 .sql files where i need to search for a specific pattern and output the results.

e.g

***file1.sql**

```
select * from mydb.ops1_tbl from something1 <other n lines>
```

***file2.sql**

```
select * from mydb.ops2_tbl from something2 <other n lines>
```

***file3.sql**

```
select * from mydb.ops3_tbl ,mydb.ops4_tbl where a = b <other n lines>
```

**Expected result**

> file1.sql mydb.ops1_tbl
>
> file2.sql mydb.ops2_tbl
>
> file3.sql mydb.ops3_tbl mydb.ops4_tbl

**Below script in powershell - able to fetch the filename**

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.sql|Select-String -pattern "mydb."|group path|select name
```

**Below script in powershell - able to fetch the line**

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.sql | Select-String -pattern "mydb." |select line
```

I need in the above format, someone has any pointers regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

1. you need to escape the dot in a RegEx to match a literal dot with a backslash `\.`
2. to get all matches on a line use the parameter  `-AllMatches`
3. you need a better RegEx to match the mydb string upto the next space
4. iterate the Select-string results with a ForEach-Object

A one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.sql|Select-String -pattern "mydb\.[^ ]+" -Allmatches|%{$_.path+" "+($_.Matches|%{$_.value})}
```

broken up

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.sql|
    Select-String -Pattern "mydb\.[^ ]+" -Allmatches | ForEach-Object{
        $_.path+" "+($_.Matches|ForEach-Object{$_.value})
    }
```

Sample output:

```
Q:\Test\2019\01\24\file1.sql mydb.ops1_tbl
Q:\Test\2019\01\24\file2.sql mydb.ops2_tbl
Q:\Test\2019\01\24\file3.sql mydb.ops3_tbl mydb.ops4_tbl
```

If you don't want the full path (despite you are recursing) like your `Expected result`,
replace `$_.path` with `(Split-Path $_.path -Leaf)`

Answer (score 1):

First, fetch the result of your file query into an array, then iterate over it and extract the file contents using regex matching:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.sql|Select-String -pattern "mydb."|group path|select name
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $str = Get-Content -Path $file.Name
    $matches = ($str | select-string -pattern "mydb\.\w+" -AllMatches).Matches.Value

    [console]::writeline("{0:C} {1:C}", $file.Name, [string]::Join(' ', $matches) ) 
}
```

I used the .NET WriteLine function to output the result for demonstration purpose only.